# Pause loop until WebBrowser navigates and loads the document

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have a web page which takes me to another page containing student information on searching by student id. I have a list of student id's. I should retrieve the student information from the second page and store it in a datatable. Here is the code

```
string id { get ; set ;} 
int lCount;
List<string> ids = new List<string>{"A1201", "A1202", "A1203"};
Datatable result = new Datatable();

private void button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   for(int i = 0 ; i < totalids ; i++)
   {
      lCount = i;
      webbrowser1.Navigate("http://www.sksit.com");
      webbrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(browser_DocumentCompleted)
   }
}

private void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.URL.toString() == "http://www.sksit.com")
   {
      HtmlElement el = webbrowser1.Document.GetElementById("sid");
      el.SetAttribute("value", ids[lCount]);

      HtmlElement cl = webbrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Search");
      cl.InvokeMember("click");
   }
   elseif(e.URL.toString() == "http://www.sksit.com/studentprofiles")
   {
      HtmlElement el = webbrowser1.Document.GetElementById("studentinfotab");
      string info = el.InnerHtml;
      string[] tableinfo = info.Split(' ');
      DataRow trow = result.newDataRow();
      for(int j =0 ; j < tableinfo.Count() ; j++)
      {
         trow[j] = tableinfo[j];
      }
      result.Rows.Add(trow);
   }
}
```

When i see the result table after execution it shows no data in it. This code works fine when a single id is passed. When it is put in a loop there is no data seen and it shows the lCount to be 2. Please throw some light on how to pause the loop till it completes loading and parsing. Thank You.

Comment: you are navigating same web browser to totalids  time under button client event for loop.. it seems to be wrong

Comment: are you bound with web browser control...instead of using open source  library .. designed for web scrapping

Comment: i visted http://www.sksit.com but did not find  element with "sid"..

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Yes i am bound to use web browser control. Strictly no open source. Thats a dummy code i have put in. My requirement is exactly similar. Can you please elaborate on your first comment. Also give some insights on how to implement this. @sm.abdullah

Comment: okay.. if I visit this URL http://www.sksit.com/studentprofiles
it shows me 404 error..http://www.sksit.com one does not contain input fields..having id "sid"
is this returning null. ?
HtmlElement el = webbrowser1.Document.GetElementById("sid");
can you make sure el is not null ?

Comment: @sm.abdullah As i stated in my earlier comment, the above code is dummy. There is no website sksit.com/studentprofiles as such. I can't post my original URL here. Hence, posted some dummy site. Please ignore the URL part and help me identify where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this. giving you rough idea..

```
string id { get ; set ;} 
    int lCount;
    List<string> ids = new List<string>{"A1201", "A1202", "A1203"};
    Datatable result = new Datatable();

    private void button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

          lCount = 0;
          webbrowser1.Navigate("http://www.sksit.com");
          webbrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new                     WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(browser_DocumentCompleted)

    }

    private void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       if(e.URL.toString() == "http://www.sksit.com")
       {
          HtmlElement el = webbrowser1.Document.GetElementById("sid");
          el.SetAttribute("value", ids[lCount]);

          HtmlElement cl = webbrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Search");
          cl.InvokeMember("click");
       }
       elseif(e.URL.toString() == "http://www.sksit.com/studentprofiles")
       {
          HtmlElement el = webbrowser1.Document.GetElementById("studentinfotab");
          string info = el.InnerHtml;
          string[] tableinfo = info.Split(' ');
          DataRow trow = result.newDataRow();
          for(int j =0 ; j < tableinfo.Count() ; j++)
          {
             trow[j] = tableinfo[j];
          }
          result.Rows.Add(trow);

           //it should be something like this.

           if(iCount < ids.Count){ 
             iCount ++;
             webbrowser1.Navigate("http://www.sksit.com");
            }

       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. Worked like Charm. You are a saviour!! @sm.abdullah